# Outlook like UI Standards

Tags: outlook-addin

Need your help.

I am in dire need of UI standards like we have in outlook, the size of the window, mesage sizes, font size stuff and all. I am trying to make few Add-ins, but clinet needs me to follow the UI standards as of outlook, request you to please help me.

Amit

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn358358.aspx

you can find them here!
Hope this is what you were looking for and is helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any guidelines specific to Outlook, but I highly recommend these user interface guidelines found in [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e49820cb-954d-45ae-9cb3-1b9e8ea7fe8c) guide.